# How to convert between these formats in unix

Tags: unix, format

I would like to convert from file 1 format to format of file 2 (below). 
I have tab  delimited File 1 (below first two lines, but the file contains 1000s lines) that have 3 parts: name, first group of numbers,second group of numbers delimited by www.
I would like to convert to format of File 2 (below). It splits if multiple entries in File1 for certain name into separate rows. The columns are tab delimited and there are 4 column: name, +, number from second group of File1, number from first group of File1.I would prefer solution for that problem in unix if possible. I would really appreciate your help.

File 1

Name_1  www 5   5   www 17  23

Name_2  www 7   54  14 www  300 16 29

Name_3 www 6 www 26

...

to

File 2

Name_1 + 17 5

Name_1 + 23 5

Name_2 + 300 7

Name_2 + 16 54

Name_2 + 29 14

Name_3 + 26 6

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some complex looking index arithmetic:

```
awk '{
    n = (NF-3)/2
    for (i=1; i <= n; i++)
        print $1, "+", $(2+i), $(NF-n+i)
}' file1 > file2
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it does not work for me. Could you indicate what I might do wrong? Also could you explain what does this part n=(NF-3/2)? Here is my command  awk '{n = (NF-3)/2 for (i=1; i <= n; i++) print $1, "+", $(2+i), $(NF-n+i)}' temp > out and here is the error: awk: {n = (NF-3)/2 for (i=1; i <= n; i++) print $1, "+", $(2+i), $(NF-n+i)}
awk:               ^ syntax error

Comment: If you put it on one line, then you need a semicolon before `for`

Comment: `NF` is the number of fields in the current record. Just try to follow the math and figure it out.

Comment: It almost works now thank you, but I wanted to have numbers swap. The group of numbers in File1 that were at the end after second www, should be now in column 3 after '+' and numbers after first www should be in the last column.Sorry if I did not explain that very well.

Comment: How should the `print` statement change to accomplish that?

Comment: obviously: print $1, "+", $(NF-n+i), $(2+i) . Thank you